# Canvas: begin path & moveTo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a little problem with Canvas.

It's simple drawing canvas application:

```
$("#drawing").mousemove(function(e) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

I need to use beginPath for create a new path. But my application doesn't work with beginPath and moveTo. (Doesn't draw a line)

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
ctx.stroke();
```

How to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `moveTo` and `lineTo` coordinates are the same (you're drawing a dot).

Make sure the coordinates are not the same:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
ctx.lineTo(e.clientX+50, e.clientY+50);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: thanks you, but I need just a dot. (I tried to use lineWidth - no result)

Comment: Ok, for a 1-pixel-dot do: ctx.fillRect(e.clientX,e.clientY,1,1);  Cheers!